# Unused 'x' in function arguments, but 'x' is needed - JSLint error

Tags: angularjs, jslint

I'm analyzing my `AngularJS` code with `JSLint`.

Many times, I have function that have multiple argumets, eg:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (ev, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    // code that uses toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams
    // but does touch use ev
})
```

and many times I need to specify all arguments, because I use last arguments.

As a result other arguments are not used, but still needed. And JSLint throws errors, eg:

> Unused 'ev'.......

Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure! You can use a [JSLint directive](http://old.jslint.com/lint.html#options):

```
/*jslint unparam:true, sloppy:true, white:true, devel:true */
/*global $rootScope*/
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (ev, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    // I'm putting in this line so that JSLint doesn't complain about an empty block
    // and also so that I can mimic your described situation.
    console.log(toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams);
});
```

In this case, `unparam:true` is the one that fixes this specific issue. (`devel` allows `console` use and a few other objects. `white` allows any whitespace, and `sloppy` allows you to skip `"use strict";`. The last two are personal preferences.)

If you only want to turn it off for this single function (or some subset of your code), you can turn `unparam` off and on like this:

```
/*jslint sloppy:true, white:true, devel:true */
/*global $rootScope*/

/*jslint unparam:true */
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (ev, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    console.log(toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams);
});
/*jslint unparam:false */
```

`unparam` is very useful for exactly these kinds of situations. Event handler function signatures like this one in 3rd party libraries would be very difficult to use without this option.